# Connection is unable to read and will timeout after being idle

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, resttemplate

`ServiceA` uses a `RestTemplate`, created using a new instance of `RestTemplateBuilder` (not the default one created by Spring), to send requests to third-party services.

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

    private static final String URL_B = "...";

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ServiceA() {
       restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .uriTemplateHandler(new UriTemplateHandler() {
                //...
            })
            .build();
    }

    public ResponseB getResponseAForServiceB() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(URL_B, ResponseB.class);
    }

}
```

When the Spring Boot app starts up, requests made by `ServiceA` to `ServiceB` (third-party) will succeed without any issues. After about 1-1.5 hours of no requests, the first request made by `ServiceA` to `ServiceB` will cause a connection timeout for failing to read but a second request will succeed. What is causing the connection to not be able to read and timeout after being idle for a bit?